# C++ function overloading confusing for string reference and anonymous function

Tags: c++

I defined following functions for string processing:

```
void sub(const std::string & repl){
}

void sub(std::function<std::string()> userfun){
}
```

When I call with an anonymous function, it is OK

```
sub([=](){return "a"; });
```

But when I call with string, it has failed

```
sub("a");
```

> error C2668: 'sub' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Is it possible to avoid ambiguous call when calling with a string against anonymous function parameter

Using Visual C++ 2013

**UPDATE2**

Create a new console project and put everyting from sketch and still failed in VC++2013

```
// overload.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <functional>
void sub(const std::string & repl) {
}

void sub(std::function<std::string()> userfun) {

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sub("a");
    return 0;
}

1>------ Build started: Project: overload, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2016-06-22 17:55:00.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\overload.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  overload.cpp
1>c:\users\xxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\overload\overload\overload.cpp(15): error C2668: 'sub' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\users\xxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\overload\overload\overload.cpp(10): could be 'void sub(std::function<std::string (void)>)'
1>          c:\users\xxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\overload\overload\overload.cpp(7): or       'void sub(const std::string &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const char [2])'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
```

UPDATE:
My VS about information:
[image]

Comment: `sub(string("a"));` or `/* const */ string a("a"); sub(a); /* skope leak */`

Comment: @MohitJain this is a possible way, but not friendly for the user, I hope to "fix" the the defination of the function to achieve the same result

Comment: can't reproduce in http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: VC++2013 - not the most renowned standards-compliant compiler out there. Can you upgrade to 2015?

Comment: I tried it with VC++ 2013 on my machine, and it compiles fine. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: @ChristianHackl sorry, what is MCVE, I tried to google it but not sure what it means.

Comment: @Boying: Have you really tried googling it? https://www.google.com/search?q=MCVE Look at the first result.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I triedit from sketch now, see the update, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compiler bug: `sub(std::string("a"));` is an adequate workaround. (Binding an anonymous temporary to a `const` reference is legal in C++.)

MSVC2013 compiles the statement

```
std::function<std::string()> foo("a");
```

Showing that `"a"` is a valid constructor argument for that type. (It appears to be using, in error, the constructor `function( std::nullptr_t )`).

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function

Comment: Why it's ambiguous with `std::function`?

Comment: this is a possible way, but not friendly for the user, I hope to "fix" the the defination of the function to achieve the same result

Comment: Added a "proof by successful compilation".

Comment: OP-s code does compile fine on various compilers I have tried - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3452728aa055626f

Comment: @Bathsheba I still can't get it. Which ctor should be applied for `const char*`? The 5th one?

Comment: @songyuanyao I suppose its `function( std::nullptr_t );` but in VS2013 nullptr probably accepts const char*

Comment: That's what I think it's doing, essentially.

Comment: `#include <string> #include <functional> void sub(const std::string & repl){ } void sub(std::function<std::string()> userfun){ } int main() {  sub([=](){return "a"; }); }` - This actually compiles fine on VC 2013. The OP's actual problem must be in some code he has not shown.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the problem is with calling `sub("a"); `

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski: Ah, right. Sorry! :) That's what happens when you don't post a complete piece of code...

Comment: btw. RexTester appears to have VS2013 as it show this error: http://rextester.com/VYRTZ95940

Comment: Yup, VC2013 does not claim to implement the C++11 standard, although some of it is there.